# SQL H2 Overlapping date interval aggregate

Tags: java, sql, date, h2, overlap

I have an SQL query using H2 syntax which returns me a list of appointments who's components are being used. This does not take in account overlapping appointments that use the same component_type_id.

Each block is an appointment using different components. Example:
There is a total of x4 component_type_id = 33.

- Appointment 1 is between 08:00 and 09:30 and using **x3** component_type_id = 33.
- Appointment 2 is between 09:00 and 11:00 and using **x1** component_type_id = 33.
  **This means between 09:00 and 09:30, all x4 resources are unavailable. I want that time frame.**

Appointments for component_type_id=33:

```
08:00 -----               <-|
08:30 |   |                 | 9 total machines are taken during this timeframe
09:00 |x3 | -----           | 
09:30 ----- |   | -----     |
10:00       |   | |   |     |                       
10:30       |x1 | |x0 |   <-|
11:00       ----- |   |
11:30             -----
```

Should return:

```
08:00                     
08:30                     
09:00 --------------      <-| All x4 component_type_id=33 are taken
09:30 --------------      <-|
10:00                                        
10:30                       
11:00       
11:30
```

---

***SIMPLIFIED TABLES:***

**APPOINTMENT**:

```
| id  | start_time           | end_time             |
| --- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 2021-05-21 8:00:00  | 2021-05-21 09:30:00 |
| 2   | 2021-05-21 09:00:00 | 2021-05-21 11:00:00 |
| 3   | 2021-05-21 09:30:00 | 2021-05-21 11:30:00 |
```

**COMPONENT**:

```
| id  | component_type_id   | name |
| --- | ----------------| ---- |
| 1   | 4               | pc12 |
| 2   | 4               | pc13 |
| 3   | 4               | pc14 |
| 4   | 3               | vm45 |
| 5   | 3               | vm46 |
| 6   | 3               | vm47 |
| 7   | 1               | gg67 |
| 8   | 1               | gg68 |
| 9   | 1               | gg69 |
| 10  | 1               | gg70 |
```

**APPOINTMENT_COMPONENT**: (cross table)

```
| id  | appointment_id| component_id|
| --- | --------------| ----------- |
| 1   | 1             | 3           |
| 2   | 1             | 4           |
| 3   | 1             | 5           |
| 4   | 2             | 1           |
| 5   | 2             | 2           |
| 6   | 2             | 3           |
| 7   | 2             | 7           |
| 8   | 3             | 4           |
| 9   | 3             | 5           |
```

---

Non aggregate query (for demonstration) :

```
select a.appointment_id, c.component_id,ct.component_type_id, a.appointment_start_time, a.appointment_end_time,
                    (select count(*) from component where component.component_id = c.component_id and component.component_type_id = 33) as total_used_component_type,
                    (select count(*) from component where component.component_type_id = 33) as total_component_type from  appointment a
    left join appointment_component ac on a.appointment_id = ac.appointment_id
    inner join component c on c.component_id = ac.component_id
    inner join component_type ct on ct.component_type_id = c.component_type_id
    and a.appointment_start_time >= '2021-05-21T08:00:00.000-05:00' and a.appointment_end_time <= '2021-05-21T16:00:00.000-05:00' and c.component_type_id=33
```

Result:
[image]

I later do *TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPE - TOTAL_USED_COMPONENT_TYPE* to check how many components are available. **My goal is to find ***unavailable*** component types between two dates**.

---

Aggregate query :

```
select appointment_id, (TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPE - SUM(TOTAL_USED_COMPONENT_TYPE)) AS TOTAL_AVAILABLE_COMPONENT_TYPE FROM (
                select a.appointment_id, c.component_id,ct.component_type_id, a.appointment_start_time, a.appointment_end_time,
                (select count(*) from component where component.component_id = c.component_id and component.component_type_id = 33) as total_used_component_type,
                (select count(*) from component where component.component_type_id = 33) as total_component_type from  appointment a
left join appointment_component ac on a.appointment_id = ac.appointment_id
inner join component c on c.component_id = ac.component_id
inner join component_type ct on ct.component_type_id = c.component_type_id
and a.appointment_start_time >= '2021-05-21T08:00:00.000-05:00' and a.appointment_end_time <= '2021-05-21T16:00:00.000-05:00' and c.component_type_id=33) 
GROUP BY Appointment_id
```

Result:

[image]

[image: Allen's Interval Algebra]

Comment: Could you explain how component id 3 can be associated with appointments id 1 and 3 at the same time, as can be seen in table APPOINTMENT_COMPONENT? Appointment 1 starts at 8:00 and finishes at 9:30... appointment 2 starts at 9:00 and ends at 11:00. That is, two appointments for a same component at the same time (from 9:00 to 9:30).

Comment: That was my mistake! They cannot overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the desired result using this query:

```
-- My goal is to find unavailable component types between two dates
select 
  busy_components.component_type_id, 
  busy_components.start_time, 
  busy_components.end_time, 
  busy_components.total 
from 
(
  select 
    cm.*, 
    greatest(ap.start_time, '2021-05-21 08:00:00'::timestamp) start_time, 
    sum(case when ctrl.event_name = 'start' then 1 else -1 end) over(partition by cm.component_type_id order by case when ctrl.event_name = 'start' then ap.start_time else ap.end_time end, ctrl.event_name, cm.id) total, 
    lead(case when ctrl.event_name = 'end' then ap.end_time end, 1, least(ap.end_time, '2021-05-21 16:00:00'::timestamp)) over(partition by cm.component_type_id order by case when ctrl.event_name = 'start' then ap.start_time else ap.end_time end, ctrl.event_name, cm.id) end_time 
  from (select 'start' event_name union select 'end' event_name) ctrl 
  inner join appointment ap on 1=1 
    and ap.start_time < '2021-05-21 16:00:00' 
    and ap.end_time   > '2021-05-21 08:00:00' 
  inner join appointment_component ac on 1=1 
    and ac.appointment_id = ap.id 
  inner join component cm on 1=1 
    and cm.id = ac.component_id 
) busy_components 
inner join 
(
  select 
    component_type_id, 
    count(*) total 
  from component 
  group by component_type_id
) all_components 
  on  all_components.component_type_id = busy_components.component_type_id 
  and all_components.total = busy_components.total 
;
```

You can view a PostgreSQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f818/11) which runs for the following data and provides the following output:

```
create table appointment(id, start_time, end_time) as 
select 1, '2021-05-21 08:00:00'::timestamp, '2021-05-21 09:30:00'::timestamp union all 
select 2, '2021-05-21 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2021-05-21 11:00:00'::timestamp union all 
select 3, '2021-05-21 09:30:00'::timestamp, '2021-05-21 11:30:00'::timestamp 
;

create table component(id, component_type_id, name) as 
select 1, 4, 'pc12' union all 
select 2, 4, 'pc13' union all 
select 3, 4, 'pc14' union all 
select 4, 3, 'vm45' union all 
select 5, 3, 'vm46' union all 
select 6, 3, 'vm47' union all 
select 7, 1, 'gg67' union all 
select 8, 1, 'gg68' union all 
select 9, 1, 'gg69' union all 
select 10, 1, 'gg70'
;

create table appointment_component(id, appointment_id, component_id) as 
select 1, 1, 3 union all 
select 2, 1, 4 union all 
select 3, 1, 5 union all 
select 4, 2, 1 union all 
select 5, 2, 2 union all 
select 6, 3, 3 union all 
select 7, 2, 7 union all 
select 8, 3, 4 union all 
select 9, 3, 5 
;
```

```
| component_type_id |           start_time |             end_time | total |
|-------------------|----------------------|----------------------|-------|
|                 4 | 2021-05-21T09:00:00Z | 2021-05-21T09:30:00Z |     3 |
|                 4 | 2021-05-21T09:30:00Z | 2021-05-21T11:00:00Z |     3 |
```

Basically, it works like this:

- First find all components running between the desired start and end time (where `start_time` is before the desired end time and `end_time` is after the desired start time).
- Next, group the components of the same `component_type_id` and order their `start_time` and `end_time` as both columns were in a single column. This way, you can cumulative count +1 busy components when you find a start event and -1 busy components when you find an end event.
- Finally, check if that count matches the amount of existing components for that `component_type_id`.

For the rows matching all steps above, the resulting start time gonna be the greatest between the desired start time and the appointment `start_time`. Also the the resulting end time gonna be the least between the desired end time or the following `end_time` where a component becomes available. This way, your results will never overflow the desired start and end time.

I think the only point you should change in this query is the cast of string date time to timestamp, because I wrote this query for the PostgreSQL fiddle, but that's a minor change.